# How to check for an invalid user id and user not banned

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a ban command and trying to check if the input is an invalid user. Then, I'm trying to check if that user is valid, and if so, check if the user is not banned.

Here's my code involved with the check:

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || await client.users.fetch(args[0]).catch(error => {
    return message.channel.send('Please enter a valid user.');
});
const checkBan = await message.guild.fetchBan(user.id).catch(error => {
    return null;
});
if (checkBan == null) {
    return message.channel.send('This user is already banned.');
}
if (!user) {
    return message.channel.send('Please specify a user.');
}

//output > "Please enter a valid user." & "This user is not banned."
```

If your input is not a valid user, it sends both error messages, and if the user is valid and is banned it does work correctly.

So my question is, why are both error messages sent if the user is invalid, and how do I fix the issue?

Comment: Show me your entire code

Comment: Or at least your client.on('message'

Comment: Does using `else if` in place of `if` resolve the issue?

Comment: @justcodin https://sourceb.in/18KpwE6htQ

Comment: @Cat no, same response

Comment: I have resolved the issue by sending the message in the catch without a return, then returning null, then checking if user is not = to null, and if it isn't, then i run the code below.